# .get() on entry box returns nothing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

when I try to get the value from an entry box in my code, it returns an empty value?, how could I fix this?, I've set the entry box to a string variable, but the variable's value remains nothing?

```
import os
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

debug = Tk()    #prevenets error on 'StringVar()'
debug.withdraw()
#global varables
users_entry = StringVar()

def about():
tkMessageBox.showinfo("About", "...")
def convert():
test = users_entry.get()
print test
def root_window():
#creates main window
root_window = Tk()
root_window.title("convert to binary")
root_window.geometry("600x400")
root_window.resizable(width = FALSE, height =FALSE)
root_window.configure(background = "gray")
#aboutButton
#about_button = Button(root_window, text = "about", command = about, width = 50)
#about_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 85, pady = 3)
#entry box for text
users_entry = StringVar()
text_entry = Entry(root_window, text = "test",textvariable = users_entry, width = 70)
text_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 3)
#convert button
convert_button = Button(root_window, text = "convert", command = convert)
convert_button.grid()
root_window.mainloop()
root_window()
debug.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the master of `StringVar` object:

```
users_entry = StringVar(root_window, value="ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `users_entry` a "global variable" in your comment, but then define a new, local `users_entry` inside `root_window`.

In `convert`, the `users_entry` will refer to the one defined at the top of the script, which is still an empty string, *not* the one defined locally in `root_window` and bound to the `Entry` box.

Put `global users_entry` at the top of each method to actually *use* the version you initialise at the top of the script.